# Laravel 5 route::controller route model binding

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm creating a new website and have been using `route::resource` and have loved being able to do a route model binding.

Using `route::controller` though variables show as `{one?}/{two?} etc...`

Is it possible to use route model binding when using `route::controller`?

I.E.

```
class UserController extends Controller {
    public function getProfile(User $user)
    {
        return $user->toJson();
    }
}
```

and

```
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');
```

would result in the following route: `/user/profile/{user}`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Route::model()` for your `Route::controller`.

But you must bind all params if you need all of them.
For example:

```
Route::model('one','App\User');
Route::model('two','App\User');
```

Be sure that your uri request is `site.com/controller/method_name/param_1/param_n`

Comment: My only issue with this would be that set for all routes. IE some routes might not be looking for a user  model as the first param.  

I haven't tried it; but if I put a route::model into a route::group, would those model binding only apply to said group; or would it also be applied to routes outside that group?